# Why is there a need for empty round braces in the print statement of lambda output "print(table())"?

Tags: python, function, lambda

I am studying Python and was checking examples on lambda functions. I would like to ask you why in the example below, there are empty round braces in the print statement `print(table())`? I tried to run the code without it, `print(table)`, and it doesn't display the values.

```
tables = [lambda x=x: x*10 for x in range(1, 11)]
 
for table in tables:
    print(table())
```

Comment: The parenthesis is how the lambda is called, without them you would just print the lambda object and not the result of calling it

Comment: `tables` is a list of `lambda` functions, and `table` is one of them. The code is calling each function and printing the value it returns.

Answer (score 1):

`table` is a lambda function, so you need to call it.

If you run this code

```py
tables = [lambda x=x: x*10 for x in range(1, 11)]
 
for table in tables:
    print(type(table))
```

you get:

```
<class 'function'>
<class 'function'>
<class 'function'>
<class 'function'>
<class 'function'>
<class 'function'>
<class 'function'>
<class 'function'>
<class 'function'>
<class 'function'>
```

If you don't call a function it gives you the function *object*, not the result of the function

Answer (score 0):

Tina is correct, but since you are still studying Python please allow me to clarify. Each element in tables is generated via a function.

When iterating (for table in tables) the function must be executed to generate each element. You can see the error more clearly if you just try:

print(tables)

which returns:

[<function . at 0x7f6c12c75c10>, <function . at 0x7f6c12c75ee0>, <function . at 0x7f6c12c75f70>, <function . at 0x7f6c12c7e040>, <function . at 0x7f6c12c7e0d0>, <function . at 0x7f6c12c7e160>, <function . at 0x7f6c12c7e1f0>, <function . at 0x7f6c12c7e280>, <function . at 0x7f6c12c7e310>, <function . at 0x7f6c12c7e3a0>]

Each element must be resolved by executing the lambda function, and this is done by adding the () in the call of table.

Comment: "Tina is correct" - Tina is the person who asked the question.

Comment: LOL. Thank you. I'm trying to read and work too fast - I'll slow down and be more careful in the future.